Creating a mutable substitute for `int` and other imutable types
I have a parameter, N that shows up in some python-based simulations.  There are several things that will be set to be equal to N.  The code relies on packages that will run things expecting N to be an integer.  (I have other parameters that are floats, but let's focus on the integer case).
I would like to be able to change the value of N later and then rerun some calculations such that everything that I've set to be N has its value updated.
So I want to do something along the lines of
class intparameter(int):
    def __new__(self, x):
        instance = int.__new__(self, x)
        self.update = lambda self,y: instance = intparameter(y) #yes, this doesn't work but hopefully it's clear what I want to happen
        return instance
    
N = intparameter(500)
<run some commands here which involves making some things equal N>
<run commands>
N.update(5000)
<run new commands here, with the new value of N automatically used>

The key thing is that I need N to be treated as if its an integer in mathemtical calculations except when I want to use N.update to update the value of that integer.
I doubt this is possible, but it would make my code much cleaner.

why not simply N: int = 500? sure, global variables are bad - but it seems that's what you're looking for (?)

@OrenIshShalom int is immutable and can only be reassigned but not updated.

integers are by nature imutable in Python.
However, everything you do with an int, if the code is in Python, has to go through the dunder methods - like __add__, __mul__, etc...for operations up to __repr__ to gets its string representation.
However, Python extensions with native code can bypass these methods to get the "actual stored value" of the int. To stay on the safe side, you'd better do a fresh inheritance of numbers.Number and implement all dunder methods. Any code which expect a native Python int will fail, but will do so raising an exception, and you will get no wrong values or delayed surprises.
On the other hand inheriting from int but keeping a "fake"  value you'd use in the dunder methods could work in some places, and use the "original" value in others - you'd be busted with hard to find incorrect results.
It could be possible to have a special mutable int which would inherit the behavior of cPython int, maybe even pre-allocate some buffer space, and be mutable, by changing the actual encoding of the value in the buffer - this would at the same time be "more reliable" in the sense it would work for everyone using it in an operation, and more prone to fail in catastrophic and pyrotecnic ways crashing the whole Python runtime along with it. But then you wouldn't need to implement all the dunder methods. :-p
Now - what might be simpler and correct to do is having your places that do you use N to fetch its value themselves, instead of passing it as a parameter. If you have control over that code, you could set N to be a ContextVar for example (user would have to do N.get()  - or even a one-element list (users would consume it as N[0] - in both cases you could set the desired value without having to pass it as an argument through all your call-chain.
A quick and dirty "Number Proxy" which will pretend it is a number and forward any dunder calls to its proxied value could be hacked more or less simply as well. Just have in mind you should not implement __hash__ and put it on a dictionary or set, otherwise bad things could happen.
class MutableInt(numbers.Number):
    for methname, method in ((methodname, method) for methodname, method in int.__dict__.items() if callable(method)):
        locals()[methname] = lambda self, *args,  method=method, **kw: method(self.value, *args, **kw)
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    __hash__ = None
    del __new__, __getattribute__
    del methname, method

And that works for any pure-Python code doing things with the number:
In [27]: m = MutableInt(10)

In [28]: m
Out[28]: 10

In [29]: m + 5
Out[29]: 15

In [30]: m.value = 20

In [31]: m + 5
Out[31]: 25

And even extensions that happen to go through the __int__, __index__  dunder methods might work.

I don't think this is possible with a subclass of int. Integers are immutable, so there probably isn't an easy way to mutate them.
However, Python defines a list of dunder methods that can be overriden to emulate a numeric type. A dataclass that stores one integer and overrides all those methods will probably be sufficient for most of your use cases:
@dataclass
class intparameter:
    value: int

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.value + other

    # Define however many of the other methods you want, potentially all of them

    def __repr__(self): # This one's optional but makes printing nicer
        return repr(self.value)

N = intparameter(500)
<run some commands here which involves making some things equal N>
<run commands>
N.value = 5000
<run new commands here, with the new value of N automatically used>

I can't vouch for its contents, but there is also a package on PyPI called mutable-primitives. It's implemented using the above approach, as far as I can tell. Its GitHub page can be found here if you'd like to verify the code yourself.
